# Can't generate JWT client with Google's node.js client library

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm trying to generate an access token via a JWT client using Google's [node.js client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics#api_authorization).

Here's the code snippet I'm following:

```
var google = require("googleapis");

// Load the service account key JSON file.
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

// Specify the required scope.
var scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"
];

// Authenticate a JWT client with the service account.
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  serviceAccount.client_email,
  null,
  serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes
);

// Use the JWT client to generate an access token.
jwtClient.authorize(function(error, tokens) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error making request to generate access token:", error);
  } else if (tokens.access_token === null) {
    console.log("Provided service account does not have permission to generate access tokens");
  } else {
    var accessToken = tokens.access_token;

    // Include the access token in the Authorization header.
  }
});
```

But I keep getting this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'JWT' of undefined

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the library is using named imports as of the [26.0.0](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases/tag/v26.0.0) node.js client release. The code works correctly when I change

```
var google = require("googleapis");
```

to

```
var {google} = require("googleapis");
```

So this looks to be a documentation error on Firebase's part.